# What is the best way to split and transform a value in Oracle SQL?

Tags: string, merge, split, casting, substr

I have a given value  eg. LDABLD6A and I need to somehow transform this into: BLD-LDA.

I can't figure out which syntax to use here.

This was my approach, which obviously didn't work:

```
SUBSTR(Concat(TABLE,4,6,'-',TABLE,1,3)) as overview,
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(col, 4, 3) || '-' || SUBSTR(col, 1, 3) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks - that was exactly what I was looking for.